# Does JBoss have a user management API which I can use?

Tags: authentication, jboss, jboss7.x, administration, user-management

I am going to run a Web App on JBoss App Server 7. Does JBoss have some sort of inbuilt user management module/API which I can use rather than code my own? Or do I have to make this module myself. I know about the default JAAS pieces providing authentication AND authorisation, however I am looking to manage, add, edit, delete users from the datasource as well.

I'm not being lazy or anything, just want to know if JBoss has an easy inbuilt way before I start :)

Google implies no so I want to make sure by asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know they don't provide any easy to managed identity provider, they "only" provide way to connect to identity provider using standard protocol like LDAP, SAML and WS-trust, openid to provide container managed authentication.

They have a idm project but it seems to provide standard protocol SSO identity backed by some identity store but doesn't provide way to manage the users.

PicketBox and PricketLink are the tow JBoss project you should look for more information.

These element can be used if you want to use global identity system, existing one, new product deployment or custom build.

(disclaimer: I have sped some time on Picket* projects documentation and I still don't think I get a good knowledge on how it works... )

Answer (score 0):

There is a web interface and a command line interface for management operations. See the [Management Clients](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Management+Clients) section of the documentation.

The [security realms](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/Security+Realms) could be what you're after. I'm not really a security expert though.

Maybe a [security domain](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/JBossAS7SecurityDomainModel) could be helpful too.

Comment: But I want to manage users in my app itself and not manually outside

Comment: If you want to manage it in your application you would have to write your own management classes. You can connect to the server with the `ModelControllerClient` and execute operations.